# python redshift delete statement not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to execute the following Redshift SQL in a Python script, but records are not being deleted. There is no error, either.

```py
sql_del = "DELETE FROM table_name where id in (select id from table2)"
cursor.execute(sql_del)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: What makes you think it is "not working"? Is it because some rows still exist that should have been deleted? If you run the same command in the Redshift SQL console, does it work differently?

Comment: My SQL query should delete the existing records in the redshift table. When I run the same query in the query editor, it deletes the existing ids, but when I run it in a Python script, it does not.

Comment: What library are you using to run these commands? I suspect that the 2nd and 3rd lines probably return a value, but your code is not storing or examining the returned information.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein,
I am using the psycopg2 library to connect to Redshift.

Comment: A thought... I wonder whether it needs a hint as to the schema to use? When using the Query Editor, there is a default schema selected. Maybe you should try `DELETED FROM schema.table_name` in case that is causing a problem.

Comment: I'd suggest a bit of debugging to help identify the problem. For example, do a SELECT before the DELETE to count the number of matching rows, then do it again _after_ the DELETE to see whether the row count has changed.